# parse the data json data using php foreach loop

Tags: php, json, foreach

I am trouble to extract data like lat lng etc from the below json data using php `foreach` loop.

```
   {
    "deals": [
      "division": {
      "timezone": "Central Time (US & Canada)",
      "lat": 32.4487,
      "timezoneOffsetInSeconds": -18000,
      "id": "abilene",
      "lng": -99.7331,
      "timezoneIdentifier": "America/Chicago",
      "name": "Abilene, TX"
     },
```

I want to parse the data as lat lng etc..
here is my php code

```
      $json = file_get_contents($url);
      $json_string1 = json_decode($json);

      foreach($json_string1->deals as $mydata)
  {

      foreach($mydata->division as $p)
      {
      echo $p->lat;
      }
     }
```

gives error `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: use `$json_string1` instead of `$json_string` variable in foreach loop

Answer (score 2):

Here's a better answer, with the assumed structure of your JSON.  If your JSON is not like this please edit your question and run your json through jsonlint or similar first.

```
<?php
$json = <<<JSON
{
    "deals": [
        {
            "division": {
                "timezone": "Central Time (US & Canada)",
                "lat": 32.4487,
                "timezoneOffsetInSeconds": -18000,
                "id": "abilene",
                "lng": -99.7331,
                "timezoneIdentifier": "America/Chicago",
                "name": "Abilene, TX"
            }
        }
    ]
}
JSON;

  $json_string1 = json_decode($json, false);

  foreach($json_string1->deals as $mydata)
  {
    echo $mydata->division->lat;
  }
?>
```

Comment: this gives a garbage value

Answer (score 0):

use `$json_string1` instead of `$json_string` variable in foreach loop

Comment: could you please write the exact error you are getting

Comment: it gives error error Trying to get property of non-object